# Quartz Scheduler : Failed to obtain DB connection from data source

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, quartz

I trying to implement `Quartz-Scheduler` in `Spring-Boot` application.

But when I'm trying to schedule job, I'getting this exception:

```
2017-03-21 15:57:42.817  INFO 12069 --- [o-8080-exec-178] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
2017-03-21 15:57:42.817  INFO 12069 --- [o-8080-exec-178] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDs': java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'myDs' [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'myDs']]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:692)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:567)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
    at com.example.controller.StudentController.getAllStudents(StudentController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDs': java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'myDs' [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'myDs']
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:778)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:834)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:690)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'myDs'
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:104)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:775)
    ... 69 more
```

quartz.properties:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 25000


#============================================================================
# Configure DataSources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1
```

I do have a database named quartz and all the quartz tables loaded into it.

application.properties:

```
#disbale Spring banner
spring.main.banner-mode=off

# Loads SQL scripts? schema.sql and data.sql
#spring.datasource.initialize=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/career_focus
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

quartz.enabled=true

# HikariCP settings
# spring.datasource.hikari.*

#60 sec
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
# max 5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
```

This is how I'm trying to Schedule a job:

```
JobDetail detail = JobBuilder.newJob().ofType(JobRunner.class).withIdentity("jobName123", "jobGroup123")
            .storeDurably().withDescription("Invoke Sample Job service...").build();

String cronExpr = "0/10 * * * * ?";
try {
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpr))
            .forJob("jobName123", "jobGroup123")
            .build();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(detail, trigger);
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:**

SchedulerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "quartz.enabled")
public class SchedulerConfig {
    //
    // @Autowired
    // List<Trigger> listOfTrigger;

    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, JobFactory jobFactory) throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        // Here we will set all the trigger beans we have defined.
        // if (!AppUtil.isObjectEmpty(listOfTrigger)) {
        // factory.setTriggers(listOfTrigger.toArray(new
        // Trigger[listOfTrigger.size()]));
        // }

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, long pollFrequencyMs) {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(pollFrequencyMs);
        factoryBean.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        // in case of misfire, ignore all missed triggers and continue :
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    // Use this method for creating cron triggers instead of simple triggers:
    public static CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, String cronExpression) {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    public static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(Class jobClass) {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
        // job has to be durable to be stored in DB:
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java

```
public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements
        ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

Comment: problem was I put `org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs` instead of `org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS`. I changed it, and its working

Comment: Haha, I used the same source from the web. Thanks for figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you should be using a LocalDataSourceJobStore to allow Quartz to use a Spring created datasource.